# Why does input[type=checkbox] not allowing CSS?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to find direct CSS to apply for checkbox. But I could only find the hacks for styling checkbox or radio button. Unlike `input[type=button]` or `[type=text]`, why would checkbox or radio button not allow the native CSS styles?

Comment: What do you mean by _native CSS styles_?

Comment: background-color, color,..

Comment: Because these elements are rendered by the operating system and the browser doesn't really have access to these elements. That's why you need to use hacks to style them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly style checkbox or radio input. It's styled by browser. If you want to do some customization, you need to hide it, and style it through pseudo element like :before/:after or just use a span etc..

Here are som simple examples: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp